# next.js - redirects to remove date from url

Tags: regex, next.js, next.js13

I'm migrating from wordpress to another platform and currently any blog entries follow this pattern:

`{root}/YYYY/MM/DD/[slug]`

The new pattern is:

`{root}/blog/[slug]`

I'm trying to create a redirect that essentially strips out the date page and replace it with 'blog' but not having much luck.

I believe the regex should be `\d{1,4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}` but tried this in numerous ways in the next.config.js file with no joy. An example:

```
      {
        source: "/(d{1,4}/d{1,2}/d{1,2})/:slug",
        destination: "/blog/:slug",
        permanent: true,
      },
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try do this stuff like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:year(\\d{1,4})/:month(\\d{1,2})/:day(\\d{1,2})/:slug',
        destination: '/blog/:slug',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! Didn't realise I'd need the year month and date props so thank you for pointing that out.